# List Properties in SPS2003 (WSS v2)

Tags: 2003, wss-2.0

Within SPS2003 (WSS v2), is it possible to query all of the lists within a given site collection and list all of the properties(owner, size, template)? It's an old platform that will be migrated in the future, and I'm trying to gather as much information as possible.